# iOS autolayout changes leading and trailing space

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have some issues with auto layout, hopefully some of you can help me =).

I add a UIView to an empty view controller, like this:
[image]

Then I add constraints for leading and trailing space, like this:

[image]

Which results in this:

[image]

I can't understand why it sets them as equal to -16.0. If I change those values to 0, then Xcode complains about the width of the gray UIView.

When I run the app on iPhone 5 simulator, it looks fine:
[image]

However, when I run the app on iPhone 6 Plus simulator it adds white space on the left and on the right:

[image]

I don't want the gray UIView to have any space from the left of from the right no matter how big the screen is. How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Just click the edit button that's on the right side of the constraints, and change the value from -16 to 0. The -16 has to do with setting the constraints to the margin rather than the edge of the view.

Comment: If I change those to 0, then Xcode automatically resizes the view like this: http://i.imgur.com/HjQi2dV.png

Comment: And if I set them to 0, and then manually set the frame from edge to edge, then I get a warning about misplacing views, and at the run time it resizes the view anyway, here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/954Jz1O.png

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Double click the constraint and open it. There select first or second item and deselect "Relative to margin". Then set your constant as 0.

Xcode is showing -16 because it is calculating space with respect to a margin and not the edges.

Check following link for more info on margins. [Editing Auto Layout Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/EditingConstraintAttributesintheAttributesInspector.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can clear all existing constraints on the view,and in Any*Any mode, add constraints for all 4 space to superview, which are Leading, Trailing, Top, Bottom. Then it will have the equal width with the screen no matter how big the screen is.

Comment: It still resizes them. I simply add constraints like this: http://i.imgur.com/wUiFX31.png, which results in this: http://i.imgur.com/4hqUuKD.png

Comment: Notice the -16, the grayview's origin x should be 0, and its width should be 600.

Comment: yes, i tried that as well, it still resizes it. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/IlnyGhi.png

Comment: Notice the yellow arrow in the pic, it means view is misplaced. Try to clear all constraints and do the above in the post again.

Comment: yellow arrow appears when I change -16 to 0. It is not possible to have that gray view from edge to edge, having leading and trailing constraints set to 0, and not seeing that yellow warning.

Comment: In the photo, Trailing space to **Container Margin** is selected, it should be Trailing space to **Super View**.